# RecyclerView no guarda valores iniciales en ArrayList

Tags: android, arraylist, recyclerview

Hola miren el siguiente gif el valor del primer item es 4.4 y esta sin checkbox(valor 0) lo cambio a 4.1 y le pongo check en el checkbox le doy a enviar temperatura el toast deberia mostrar en la primera fila el valor 4.4 y el 0 despues del "-----" debería aparecer el 4.1 y el 1 en el item 165 pero en los dos lados sale igual he creado un arraylist solo se ejecuta una vez ya que hay un contador y es la primera vez que se llena el arraylist que debería tener los valores iniciales sin modificar nada pero no es así se modifica a los últimos valores modificados de del RecyclerView.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He aquí el código de la lista sin modificar que al final se modifica

```
private List<PalletTempModel> palletTempModelListSinModificar;

if(contador == 0){
            palletTempModelListSinModificar = palletTempModelList;
            contador++;
}
```

Y he aqui el toast con el que muestro los valores del **palletTempModelListSinModificar** y **ordenTempAdapter**

```
btnEnviarTemperatura.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String message = "";
                for(int i = 0; i <palletTempModelListSinModificar.size(); i++){
                    message = message + palletTempModelListSinModificar.get(i).getNumePallet() + " | ";
                    message = message + palletTempModelListSinModificar.get(i).getTemperatura() + " | ";
                    message = message + Integer.toString(palletTempModelListSinModificar.get(i).getRutaPallet()) + " | ";
                    message = message + "\n";
                }
                message = message + "-----------------------------\n";
                for(int i = 0; i <ordenTempAdapter.getPalletTempModelList().size(); i++){
                    message = message + ordenTempAdapter.getPalletTempModelList().get(i).getNumePallet() + " | ";
                    message = message + ordenTempAdapter.getPalletTempModelList().get(i).getTemperatura() + " | ";
                    message = message + Integer.toString(ordenTempAdapter.getPalletTempModelList().get(i).getRutaPallet()) + " | ";
                    message = message + "\n";
                }
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enviar Temperatura \n" + message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.i("enviar Temperatura", "Temperatura\n" + message);
            }
        });
```

Por favor ayudenme a que el **palletTempModelListSinModificar** no cambien los valores.

Les dejo el código aquí --> https://github.com/Miguel546/recyclerviewET

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya lo resolví con esta pregunta https://stackoverflow.com/questions/715650/how-to-clone-arraylist-and-also-clone-its-contents con la que tiene 208 votos la resolví era cuestión de implementar Cloneable en PalletTempModel y luego clonar todos los elementos con el método clone().

Así de esta manera

```
public static List<Dog> cloneList(List<Dog> list) {
    List<Dog> clone = new ArrayList<Dog>(list.size());
    for (Dog item : list) clone.add(item.clone());
    return clone;
}
```

Aquí el código resuelto --> https://github.com/Miguel546/recyclerviewET

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu contribución, recuerda agregar el código esencial de los enlaces ya que en ocasiones los enlaces pueden perder la información y la respuesta ya no sería útil, revisa [answer] saludos.

Answer (score 0):

ví to código y creo que el problema es cuando creas una copia de `palletTempModelListSinModificar` en línea 43. Estás creando una copia con referencias en lugar de clonar simplemente los objectos. Por eso es que cuando uno se modifica, la otra lista, como es referencia, también ve los mismos cambios.

La primera y más sencilla solución que puedo pensar ahorita es la siguiente:

```java
public static void copiarList(List<PalletTempModel> copia, List<PalletTempModel> av) {
    copia.clear();
    for (int i = 0; i < av.size(); i++) {
        PalletTempModel temp = av.get(i);
        PalletTempModel palletTempModel = new PalletTempModel();
        palletTempModel.numePallet = temp.getNumePallet();
        palletTempModel.temperatura = temp.getTemperatura();
        palletTempModel.rutaPallet = temp.getRutaPallet();
        copia.add(palletTempModel);
    }
}
```

y en lugar de usar

```java
palletTempModelListSinModificar = palletTempModelList;
```

usa:

```java
copiarList(palletTempModelListSinModificar, palletTempModelList);
```